# printf function won't print reversed string

Tags: string, printf, reverse

I have to write a function which gets a string and then reverses it. I wrote this code, which gave me no compilation errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char *reverse(char *str);

int main(void){

    char string[100];
    printf("Insert the string to be inverted: ");
    gets(string);
    reverse(string);
    printf("Inverted string is: %s\n", string);
    }

char *reverse(char *str){

    char h;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0, j=strlen(str); i<j; i++, j--){

        h=str[i];
        str[i]=str[j];
        str[j]=h;
        }

    }
```

Only problem I get is that, apparently, `printf` won't print the reversed string. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is at `str[strlen(str)]`?

Comment: Never use the `gets` function. It's inherently unsafe (what if the user types 200 characters, or your cat sits on the keyboard?), and it's been removed from the language as of the 2011 standard. `fgets` is a little trickier to use, but it can be used safely.

Answer (score 1):

The reversed string has the terminator `\0` at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen(str)` gives you the size of the string, i.e. the index of the terminating null character.

You don't want to swap the null terminator, so `strlen(str) - 1` is the index of the last character you want to swap.

Therefore, `j` should start at `strlen(str) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize at first that strlen included \0 in its analysis of the string. Now the program works. Thanks!